# How to make one-click buttons?

Tags: vb.net

I have several buttons in which all of them have come codes. I want the user to only can make click the buttons once. How can I do it without having a long disable buttons code?

```
Dim oneClick As Integer
Private Sub btnPro_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPro.Click
    oneClick += 1
    If oneClick = 1 Then
        Dim ucP As New ucPro
        fillMenu(ucP)
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the code  I come up with.

**EDIT :** The point is that I want to click a button once, but the others can be clicked. For example, I have a form with 6 buttons, every button has some codes. If I click Button1, it'll do such code only once, therefore if I click it again, it will not do that code, because it already did it. Then, if I click Button2, it'll do the code once. And what about if I click Button1 again? well, it'll be able to do that code because I clicked to another button.

Sorry for the way I explain myself. I hope you get it.

Comment: you mean , user can only click once on a button for entire session or specific time period?

Comment: Are you saying, without actually saying, that you only want the user to be able to click one of the `Buttons` and then they all get disabled? If not then I don't see what the issue is. Disabling a `Button` is one line of code so just add that to each event handler. If you want something specific then please include an explanation of that in your question.

Comment: I don't want to disable the buttons. I want the user to be able to click one button once but the others are able to be clicked.

Comment: Are you talking about "radio buttons"?

Comment: @MyNameIsInYourHeart What's the problem with the code you posted? It should be working correctly, except that you need a variable for **each** button you have, not one variable for all of them. And as an improvement, you could use `Static` variable in that case. See [Static - Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/static)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep track of last clicked button and you can use one handler for all involved buttons

```
Private _lastClickedButton As Button = Nothing

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    If button Is _lastClickedButton Then Exit Sub

    _lastClickedButton = button

    ' Now based on button instance you can execute corresponding logic/method
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your rather poor explanation, it sounds like what you actually mean is that you only want each button to act once in a row, i.e. once you click a button you need to click another button before the first button does anything again. In that case, the proper way to handle this is to not use `Button` controls.

Instead of using `Button` controls and handling their `Click` events, you should be using `RadioButton` controls and handling their `CheckedChanged` events. You can set the `Appearance` property to `Button` and they will look just like regular `Buttons`. When checked, they will appear depressed and that will indicate to the user that they can't be used again.

Here's an example of a form using such controls:

[image: RadioButton buttons]

And here's what the appropriate code might look like:

```vb
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        'Do something.
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        'Do something else.
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton3_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        'Do yet something else.
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's what the form might look like when a `RadioButton` has been checked:

[image: Checked RadioButton]

As you can see, it's nice and clear to the user which one they cannot use.

EDIT:

If you are really determined to use `Button` controls then you absolutely should be disabling them as that is the standard way that feedback has been provided to the user for decades. It's very simple to disable a `Button` if and only if it is the last one clicked. Here's an example:

```vb
Private Sub AllButtons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click,
                                                                       Button2.Click,
                                                                       Button1.Click
    For Each btn In Controls.OfType(Of Button)
        btn.Enabled = (btn IsNot sender)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Do something.
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Do something else.
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'Do yet something else.
End Sub
```

Note that you can handle multiple events with a single method and multiple methods can handle a single event, both of which are demonstrated here. All four of those methods were generated automatically by the designer, so I just had to add the body code. Note that the first method assumes that all `Button` controls on the form will be treated this way. If that's not the case then would need a slight adjustment but nothing too major.